# Can't find Data Flow Diagram option in Visio Standard 2010

Tags: visio

While trying to create Flow Diagram using Visio Standard 2010 version, I am unable to find the "Software and Database --> Data Flow Diagram" option or the UML stencils to create the flow diagram.

> Is the UML stencils available only in Visio professional version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, UML stencils are availible in Professional and Premium editions.
[Visio 2010 Edition Comparison](http://www.enpointe.com/images/html/Visio_2010_Edition_Comparison.htm)

3rd-party add-ons are available that bring data-flow diagrams to Visio Standard. Please have a look at: http://www.sandrila.co.uk/visio-dfd/